# Android Mail API

Tags: android, email

I've been trying to research this lately. Is there an android API that I can use and add onto it? I want to make a plug-in for an email app but I don't want to make an entire email application.

So pretty much I want something that already handles send and receiving email all I want to be able to do with my app is add onto the email before it is sent.

Is this possible or do I have to create an entire mail application to do this?

Comment: There is an extensive example of JavaMail API usage in this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are none built in to Android.  However, I've use Javamail and it works just fine.